# Radius of Convergence of Legendre ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, power-series

I solved the Legendre ODE:

$$(1-x^{2})\frac{\mathrm d^{2}{y}}{\mathrm d{x}^{2}} - 2x \frac{\mathrm d{y}}{\mathrm d{x}} + l(l+1)y = 0$$

Using power series, and I got the following expression as the solution:

$$y(x) = c_{1}y_{1}(x) + c_{2}y_{2}(x)$$

where

$$ y_{1} = x + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!} \prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left ( l+(-1)^{k}k \right ) \cdot x^{2n+1} \right ]$$

$$ y_{2} = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!} \prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left ( l+(-1)^{k}(k-1) \right ) \cdot x^{2n} \right] $$

How can I find the radius of convergence of the solution?

I tried to use the Ratio Test on the general term of the first solution ($y_{1}$) but

$$a_{n} = \frac{(-1)^{n} \cdot x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left ( l+(-1)^{k}k \right ) $$

We get:

$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |= \left | x^{2} \right | = x^{2}$$

What can I do with this information? How can I find the radius of convergence of the solution of the Legendre equation?

Comment: The ratio test involves examining the ratio of two successive terms, including the x^n factors (not just the coefficients).

Comment: You're right. Post edited.

Comment: For what values of x^2 will L be less than 1?  (The ratio test says that if L is less than 1 then the series converges.)

Comment: For -1<x<1.
So can I say that the convergence radius is 1? And if the radius of the second solution (y2) is different than 1, should I just pick the smallest?

Answer (score 1):

There's a theorem that says for $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y = 0$, the radius of convergence of the solutions is at least as big as the radii of convergence of the series for $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.   For your equation, $p(x) = -2x/(1-x^2).$  Since this function has poles at $1$ and $-1$, the radius of convergence of the series (centered at $0$) is the distance to the nearest pole.  So $1$.  Likewise for $q(x)$.  So you know the radius of converges of your two solutions is at least $1$.

Comment: How to test at these poles and beyond these poles? Can you suggest where to find this theorem to read.?